# Visual Studio Button BackColor Not Changing

Tags: visual-studio, button

I'm adding a feature to my GUI (C#, windows form) to indicate whether the system is busy. For my GUI, when certain button is click, it will send out command to I2C adapter and this will take a while until you can click another button. So now I want a indicator (button with color) as kind of a "red or green light" to tell the user whether the system is busy. I used button.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red; at the beginning of the button_click event to turn the indicator red and similarly to turn green at the end but this only works if a message box is triggered during the event. If the event completes without message box popping out, then the indicator doesn't change color and that's not what I want. Does any you guys know how I can fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a classic **threading** problem.  Your code to communicate with the I2C adapter is blocking the UI thread preventing the control from updating its color.  Add a [BackgroundWorker Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to your form and do the communication in the `DoWork()` handler.  Change the color before calling `RunWorkerAsync()` and change the color back in the `RunWorkerCompleted()` event.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem! One more question. Now I have several backgroundworker cause I have several buttons. What will happen if I click another button when the one I clicked before is still executing? From what I have, I see the light turns green when I clicks another button but I'm not sure whether this will affect the execution.

Comment: They can all run at the same time.  Are they all communicating with different devices?

Comment: They are all communicating through the same I2C adapter. There are 4 buttons. Read and write for 2 I2C device.

Comment: From a threading standpoint, there is no issue with all of the buttons being clicked at the same time.  From a hardware standpoint, however, I have no idea as I've never used an "I2C adapter" and I don't know what it is or what its capabilities are; sorry.

Comment: ok. Thank you so much for your help!